# Got NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams

Tags: java

No class found when I am trying to create a bean in Spring Framework.

```
[2017-06-15 18:25:33, ERROR, FrameworkServlet (470),localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'interceptorInitializator' defined in file [D:\Program Files\tomcat8\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\cn\org\farseer\esb\interceptors\init\InterceptorInitializator.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cn.org.farseer.esb.interceptors.init.HandlerInterceptors': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)

Comment: i have no idea why it like that when i put it to my spring program.  while i a m doing junit test, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing solr-common-1.3.0.jar in your classpath

For such issues goto [findjar](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/solr/common/params/SolrParams.html)